# Android Big Nerd Ranch Action Bar Item not showing up

Tags: android, xml

I'm working through the Big Nerd Ranch Android book, and I'm trying to get an action bar "+" icon to show along with text if there's room with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_new_crime"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
    android:title="@string/new_crime"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
</menu>
```

I've set setHasOptionsMenu to true,tried rotating the device, as well as changing ifRoom to always, yet the "+" and "new crime" text never shows up. The only thing I get is the vertical "..." with "new crime" as an option. I'm using GenyMotion as my emulator if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
android:showAsAction="always|withText"
```

or

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

instead of

```
app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
```

Comment: Yeah that gets it to work, but Android Studio gives me a red lint error saying: Should use app:showAsAction with the appcompat library with xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto". What does this mean?

Comment: if you want to use "app:showAsAction" then try adding this to the top of your xml: xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"